# Evaluate cell's value into path

Tags: excel, vba

I have this value **"ThisWorkbook.FullName"** stored in **A1** cell on **Worksheets(1)**

In my macro, I need to take the cell's value and evaluate it in the path, for example **"D:\Users\delta\Desktop\Projects\Cars\test.xlsm"**

By executing the code below I get the string `ThisWorkbook.FullName`. And I want to get the result of execution `ThisWorkbook.FullName` command, i.e. path (string) to current Workbook location

Is there any way to do that? I do some search in Google with no success.

```
Public Sub try()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Text ' this should be evaluated
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to/need to do this, out of curiosity?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "evaluate"? Your code merely shows you wanting to print it to the debug window.

Comment: Q: Why are you trying to/need to do this, out of curiosity?
A: My macro will deal with Access database (test.accdb), which name is just like Excel's file. By default, Access file is located in folder with Excel file. But it can be moved somewhere else, or location of both files may be changed in future.
I want to have an opportunity to point new path to Access file just by editting A1 cell

Comment: No need to save the path. You can use `ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & test.accdb` to access the file

Comment: Q: What exactly do you mean by "evaluate"? Your code merely shows you wanting to print it to the debug window
A: Sorry, English is not my native, maybe "evaluate" is not correct. By executing the code above I get the string "ThisWorkbook.FullName". And I want to get the result of execution "ThisWorkbook.FullName" command, i.e. path (string) to current Workbook location, for example "D:\Users\delta\Desktop\Projects\Cars\test.xlsm"

Comment: It looks like you want to write a code expression in cell A1 which should get evaluated at run-time. Is that correct understanding?

Comment: Q: It looks like you want to write a code expression in cell A1 which should get evaluated at run-time. Is that correct understanding? A: Yes, that is correct understanding

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, you really do not need to evaluate the variable as you can pass the value set in the cell. Below is an example which you can adopt.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim strAcDb As String
    strAcDb = strAccDBPath("Test.Accdb")
    If strAcDb = "" Then
        MsgBox "Access DB not found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

Private Function strAccDBPath(strDbName As String) As String
    If Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & strDbName) <> "" Then
        strAccDBPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & strDbName
    ElseIf Dir(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value) <> "" Then
        strAccDBPath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value
    Else
        strAccDBPath = ""
    End If
End Function
```

**Note:** At any rate, do not use `Range.Text` method which may lead to some unexpected results! Use `Value` Or `Value2` instead.